# How do you split a string into different sections inside a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

For example, I have a list:
`[['aabbbb'], ['bbbbab'], ['babbab'], ['baaaaa'], ['bbbaaa'], ['bbbbaa']]`
how do I split it so that I get `[['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],`... etc? It would be very useful thanks!

Comment: You can already iterate over and index individual characters in a string, what do you want to accomplish with this?

Comment: [ list(i) for i in lst]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

```py
mylist = [['aabbbb'], ['bbbbab'], ['babbab'], ['baaaaa'], ['bbbaaa'], ['bbbbaa']]

new_list = [list(item[0]) for item in mylist]
```

This will return,

```
[['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b'], ['b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b'], ['b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']]
```

Comment: Or `new_list = [list(item) for item, in mylist]` for extra smoothness :)

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below

```
oldList = [['aabbbb'], ['bbbbab'], ['babbab'], ['baaaaa'], ['bbbaaa'], ['bbbbaa']]
newList = []
for i in oldList:
   newList.append(list(i[0]))
```

Comment: No need for a new list, use range(len(old_list) and then old_list[i] = list(old_list[i][0])